# Encoding '.' (dot) into Angular HTTP call

Tags: angular, urlencode, angular-httpclient

I want to make an HTTP request using some data I previously encoded, but when I send the encoded string, the `.` (dot) gets decoded.

```
return this._http.get(`${this._const.SECURITY_URL}/api/find/myEmail%40gmail%2Ecom`);
```

so the actual call which is being made:

```
${this._const.SECURITY_URL}/api/find/myEmail%40gmail%2Ecom
```

becomes

```
${this._const.SECURITY_URL}/api/find/myEmail%40gmail.com
```

I need `'.'` to be sent as `%2E`. What could I do?

Comment: Are you using `@angular/http` or `@angular/common/http`? Which versions?

Comment: 1) How did you test this? 2) why is it a problem? (should have the same meaning in an URL)

Comment: I am using `@angular/common/http` ("@angular/http": "^5.0.0"). I did the call from my application and the result can be seen on the browser's Network tab.
This is a problem because the server doesn't return the data if I send `.` instead of `%2E`.